# Qt problem: No QProgressBar animation with minimum and maximum steps set to 0

Tags: c++, qt

I have got a problem with my QProgressBar and I hope someone got an idea...

I have created a progress dialog with a QProgressBar on my own. I set minimum and maximum steps to 0 so that the progress indicates my program is busy (the animation thing...).

I show() this progress dialog and activated the Qt::WindowModal for this dialog.

The problem: I use this dialog while copying files but the progress bar stops and no animation anymore to indicate my program is still busy. I use the windows function 'SHFileOperation' to copy one directory with a lot of file to a destination. This, of course, produces a lot of load on the system but at least the progress should continue moving.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
BearHead

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the `SHFileOperation` call will block the main event loop. Therefore, no events will be processed preventing the `QProgressBar` from being updated.

To fix this you could perform the copy action in a separate thread. The easiest way to go about this is using Qt Concurrent, for example as follows:

```
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(SHFileOperation, ...);
QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), dialog, SLOT(close()));
```

Assuming `dialog` is a pointer to your progress dialog.

Btw, why do you use `SHFileOperation` instead of the operations provided by `QDir` and `QFile`?